# Servlet: is there any way to know the response alert at client side

Tags: javascript, servlets, iframe

please clear my doubts, here i am sending `form` data to a server and getting `response` if success.

```
<form action="/test" method="post" target="iframe"> .....  </form>
```

as you can see i have given `target` to a `iframe` & this defined somewhere in same page.
if server send response back to client then only `iframe` would be ***refresh or reload*** instead of the whole page. Right?

**My Question is :** when iframe reload ??

option 1 : on submit (just after clicking the `submit` button)  OR

option 2 : it waits until response received successfully.

I think `page/iframe reload`, just after clicking the submit button. then ***how can i relod the iframe only after getting response.***

Here is my `js` function which alert the response text.

```
    $(function() {
      $('#iframe-id').load(function() {
            alert( $(this).find('body').html() ); 
  /* but it returns null while it loads the response text, as i can see  
      the response text in firebug console */
          });
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Iframe starts loading the server response, as soon as you submit the form. After it finishes loading iframe's *onload* event is fired.

**UPDATE** after JS added to the question

**this** keyword is refferencing to the IFRAME element on the main page, **NOT** to the document/DOM of the IFRAME. To reach iframe's content use following

```
$(function() {
  $('#ifr').load(function() {            
        alert( $(this.contentWindow.document).find('body').html() );  
      });
});
```

**UPDATE 2** this works for me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <script src="jquery.js"    type="text/javascript"></script>  
  <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#ifr').load(function() {      
            alert( $(this.contentWindow.document).find('body').html() );  
        });
    });
  </script>
 </head>
<body>
  <form action="nextfile.html" method="post" target="iframe">
    <input type='text' name='name' value='namevalue'>
    <button type='submit'>submit</button>
  </form>

  <iframe id='ifr' name='iframe' src='nothing.html'></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok. but don't know why i am getting `null response text alert` when _iframe's onload event_ is fired although in firebug console, i can see the response text in `iframe`

Comment: What do you mean by "response text". It should be page content of the iframe. Resp. innerHTML of the BODY.

Comment: yes, i mean to say that. please take a look of the question as i have describe my `js`

Comment: yes, i modified my code in project and checked it now but still i am getting the null.

Comment: what do you see if you alert just 'THIS'? Is there BODY present when you inspect it with firebug?

Comment: yes,it is there and also the expected response contents in _iframe's body_

Comment: thanks Jan Pfeifer for the effort, i traced the exact problem. ` if server send _xml_ type data then it alerts null/nothing and if server send simple text type contents then it alert exactly what i expected`. is there any idea why not `$(this.contentWindow.document).find('body').html() ` reads the xml type body contents.

Comment: It should be well formed HTML document WITH BODY to use find('body') and HTML. However I have tried it with simple XML loaded and it worked, except in IE where is XML auto XSL transformed to 'clickable' HTML. Consider using AJAX to deal with XML.

Comment: error in firefox: `This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.`